# on my windows 2008 machine rt.jar is deleted from jre\lib folder after reboot

Tags: windows, java

I am observing a strange behavior on my Windows machines. I have a Server application(jboss 6.1.0) that uses Java JRE 1.6u29.

Machine reboot is causing the rt.jar file within the JRE to be deleted.

As a result, this corrupts the JVM and causes to the Server application to not startup (after the reboot).

Any help on how I could trace the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we uninstall our application we are uninstalling java also(our installer is installanywhere). since IA is java dependent instead of deleting the rt.jar while uninstalling java, it just marks the file to be deleted upon reboot. so when the vm is rebooted this file(rt.jar) is deleted.

When i install the application again it installs java also and everything works fine, but when i reboot the vm, since rt.jar is deleted java gets corrupted. so rebooting the vm after uninstalling our application solved the problem.